# Bidirectional Many-to-many relationships in Spring JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Im having trouble with many-to-many Bidirectional mapping using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate as JPA provider. The bidirectional relationship mapping allows you to navigate the association in both directions and that is what i need. I have two entities: `Artist` and `Song`. When i get an artist i want to get all his songs and vice versa, when i get a song i want to get the artists of that song. This results in a recursive error which, as i researched could be solved with @JsonIdentityInfo or using @JsonIgnore, but neither if them doesnt give me the json i truly want.

The Artist Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "artist")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "artist_songs", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "song_id") })
    private Set<Song> songs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and the Song Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "song")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "src")
    private String src;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "songs")
    private Set<Artist> artists = new HashSet<>();
}
```

My problem is that when I make a call to get these entities i get these JSON objects:

```
// THE JSON I GET WHEN I CALL http://localhost:8080/api/artists
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "artist1",
        "image": "artist1.png",
        "songs": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "song 1",
                "src": "spng1.mp3",
                "image": "song1.png",
                "artists": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "song 2",
                "src": "song2.mp3",
                "image": "song2.png",
                "artists": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "artist2",
        "image": "artist2.png",
        "songs": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "song 3",
                "src": "song3.mp3",
                "image": "song3.png",
                "artists": [
                    2
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

// THE JSON I GET WHEN I CALL http://localhost:8080/api/songs

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "song 1",
        "src": "spng1.mp3",
        "image": "song1.png",
        "artists": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "artist1",
                "image": "artist1.png",
                "songs": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "title": "song 2",
                        "src": "song2.mp3",
                        "image": "song2.png",
                        "artists": [
                            1
                        ]
                    },
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    2,
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "song 3",
        "src": "song3.mp3",
        "image": "song3.png",
        "artists": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "artist2",
                "image": "artist2.png",
                "songs": [
                    3
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The JSON objects I want are like these:

```
// THE ARTIST ENTITY
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "artist2",
        "image": "artist2.png",
        "songs": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "title": "song 1",
              "src": "song1.mp3",
              "image": "song1.png",
//REMOVES THE FIELD artists INSIDE SONG. KEEPS THAT FIELD ONLY WHEN I MAKE THE CALL TO GET ALL SONGS
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "title": "song 2",
              "src": "song2.mp3",
              "image": "song2.png",
//REMOVES THE FIELD artists INSIDE SONG. KEEPS THAT FIELD ONLY WHEN I MAKE THE CALL TO GET ALL SONGS
            }
        ]
    }



// THE SONG ENTITY
{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "song 1",
        "src": "song1.mp3",
        "image": "song1.png",
        "artists": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "artist2",
                "image": "artist2.png",
//REMOVES THE FIELD songs INSIDE ARTIST. KEEPS THAT FIELD ONLY WHEN I MAKE THE CALL TO GET ALL ARTISTS
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Look into the concept of a junction table. It's easier to break up the many-to-many relationship itself into two one-to-many relationships. Think of if you had `books` and `authors` (many to many), then you'd want a `book_author` table that contains entries of `(book_id, author_id)`. The advantage is to find all books of an author, it's now one-to-many, and all authors of a book is also one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

The Jackson annotations you are looking for is a combination of `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`. You can place it on the both ends of the relationship. However it can only be used for *one-to-one*, *one-to-many* and *many-to-one* relationships. Not for *many-to-many*.

That's why you should structurally decompose your bidirectional *many-to-many* relationship to two *many-to-one* relationships (as already suggested in the comment by @Rogue).

**Here is the complete solution**

First we will define a composite key class:

```
@Embeddable
class ArtistSongKey implements Serializable {

    Long artistId;

    Long songId;

    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
    // hashcode and equals implementation
}
```

Using this composite key class, we will create the entity class, which models the join table:

```
@Entity
class ArtistSong {

    @EmbeddedId
    ArtistSongKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @MapsId("artistId")
    Artist artist;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @MapsId("songId")
    Song song;

    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

After this, we can configure the inverse references in the Artist and Song entities:

```
class Artist {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "song")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<ArtistSong> songsOfArtist;

    // ...
}

class Song {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artist")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<ArtistSong> artistsOfSong;

    // ...
}
```

Please note the added Jackson annotations which should fix the recursion error and should provide the desired layout of JSON objects.

Based on: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many